# How to extract elements which can be assined to int() from a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list something like this:

```
l=["1", "a", "b", "2", "c"]
```

I want to extract the list `["1", "2"]` or `[1, 2]` from `l`.

In other words, I want to extract elements `e` which `int(e)` is valid.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

two basic ways to do this.

1. [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#str.isdigit) is a string method that will return a bool whether or not that number is digit-only. Note that `assert '1.5'.isdigit() == False`.
2. `int('1')` works, but `int('a')` throws a `ValueError`. You can catch that error, and only accept values that don't throw errors.

Comment: Minor edit - `int('1.5')` also throws a `ValueError`, since it is a float.

Comment: @TheGamer007 thanks, edited. I thought it gave you `1` (I actually still think it should ;D)